# If $f\colon[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function, is it true that $\mathcal{W}(f,P) \leq V_f[a, b]$ for any partition $P$ of $[a,b]$?

Tags: real-analysis, bounded-variation

Let $f\colon[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuos function, is it true that $\mathcal{W}(f,P) \leq V_f[a, b]$ for any partition $P$ of $[a,b]$?

Where $V_f[a,b] = \sup \{ v_f(P):  \text{P is a partition of} [a,b]\}$ is the total variation and $\mathcal{W}(f,P)$ is defined as follows:
Let $f\colon[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $P= \{x_0,...,x_n\}$ a partition of $[a,b]$. For each $k \in \{1,...,n\}$, we define $M_k = \sup \{f(x):x\in[x_{k-1},x_k]\}$ and $m_k = \inf\{f(x):x\in[x_{k-1},x_k]\}$. Then $\mathcal{W}(f,P) = \sum_{k=1}^n M_k-m_k$.

Intuitively, I can't find any scenario where I would have $\mathcal{W}(f,P) > V_f[a, b]$, since I could just divide $[a,b]$ into $P_i$ intervals where $f$ would be monotonic, and then $\mathcal{W}(f,P_i)$ would be equal to the variation of $f$ on each of those $P_i$ intervals, making $\mathcal{W}(f,P) = V_f[a, b]$ in the worst case scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Since $f$ is continuous there exist points $y_k,z_k$ in $[x_{k-1}, x_k]$ such that $M_k=f(y_k)$ and $m_k =f(z_k)$. So $\mathcal W(f,P) =\sum |f(y_k) -f(z_k)| \leq V_f[a,b]$.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the very last inequality, isn't that what I need to prove? I understand you used the definition of $\mathcal W(f,P)$ and the extreme value theorem to find each $y_k,z_k$. I know $ V_f[a,b]$ is the supremum of the variations of any partition, but, to which partition is  $\sum |f(y_k) -f(z_k)|$ refering to?

Comment: You have to add points to the collection $\{y_k,z_k\}$ to make it a partition. In the definition of total variation if you omit some of the terms in $\sum |f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})|$ you will get a sum that is less than or equal to the total variation.

Comment: So, I would have $P' =\{x_0,\min\{y_1,z_1\},x_1,...,x_{n-1},\min\{y_n,z_n\},x_n\}$  as a refinement of $P$, and then $\sum |f(y_k) -f(z_k)| \leq v_f(P') \leq v_f(P) \leq V_f[a,b]$, am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: You need both $\min \{y_k,z_k\}$  and $\max \{y_k,z_k\}$, but otherwise,you have got the idea.